# Excel VBA - if/then statement - Identifying cells with a dash

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a VBA line where if cell A1 contains a dash anywhere in the cell, then B1 will say "Blue". If there is no dash, then B1 would say "Red".

I have the following code written, but it's not working and I'm not sure if I'm doing the "like" part correctly:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(RC[-1]=" - ",""Blue"",""Red"")"
```

Thank you for any help you can provide! I've done so much searching, but have been unable to find any examples that didn't include specific numbers or text.

Comment: To create an Excel formula that will do this, suggest you use the `FIND` function.  In VBA you could use `Like` or `InStr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(""-"",RC[-1])),""Blue"",""Red"")"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a simple VBA script like this:

```
Sub Test()
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1")

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

                For x = 1 To sh1.Cells(rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

                    If InStr(1, sh1.Range("A" & x).Value, UCase("-"), 1) > 0 Then sh1.Range("B" & x).Value= "Red"
                    If InStr(1, sh1.Range("A" & x).Value, UCase("-"), 1) < 0 Then sh1.Range("B" & x).Value = "Blue"

                Next x

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Or a one-liner:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISERROR(FIND(""-"",RC[-1])),""Red"",""Blue"")"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that put a formula in every "B" column cells it's a good pratice, Excel can take a long time to calculate.

Try this:

```
Sub Example()

    mySheet.Cells(1, "B").Value = IIf(Not InStr(1, mySheet.Cells(1, "A"), Chr(45), vbTextCompare) = 0, "Blue", "Red")

End Sub
```

You can loop through every cell you want to put that condition using this code.

Functions:

**IIf** is equals to Excel Worksheet Function "IF".

**InStr** search a string in another string, you can pass a unique char as criterea. I used chr(**45**) because it returns a char according to the passed code, 45 references to **Dash** code.

Answer (score 0):

The error, corrected (but not pointed out) in several of the other answers lies in changing your formula from

`" - "`

to

`"" - ""`

i.e. going from single double-quotes around your `-` to double double-quotes. The single quote is ending your string - you can even see that the `-` shows up in black text in your question instead of red text, therefore, it's not part of the string being inserted into `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1`.